# How to add the directory of a batch file to Windows PATH?

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I have some Python code, developed for Linux, from a repository that I would prefer not to change.
The code uses the `subprocess` Python module to call a command line tool named `colmap`.

To get this code working under Windows, I installed `colmap`, added the `bin` folder containing `colmap.exe` to the `PATH` as well as the parent folder which contains the file `COLMAP.bat`. I then also had to change the Python code to run `colmap.bat` instead of `colmap` via `subprocess.run`.
The latter step I would like to avoid, as it would make the Python code incompatible with Linux/Mac and I would like to avoid adding an OS check via `platform.system()`.

Is there a way to add `colmap.exe` to the `PATH`, so that it can be called via `colmap` by `cmd.exe`?

Like I said, the `bin` folder is already on the `PATH`. I already unsuccessfully tried to create a shortcut to `COLMAP.bat` with the name `colmap` as well as renaming `COLMAP.bat` to `colmap`.

This is the content of the batch file:

```
set SCRIPT_PATH=%~dp0

set PATH=%SCRIPT_PATH%\lib;%PATH%
set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%SCRIPT_PATH%\lib\plugins;%QT_PLUGIN_PATH%

set COMMAND=%1
set ARGUMENTS=
shift
:extract_argument_loop
if "%1"=="" goto after_extract_argument_loop
set ARGUMENTS=%ARGUMENTS% %1
shift
goto extract_argument_loop
:after_extract_argument_loop

if "%COMMAND%"=="" set COMMAND=gui

"%SCRIPT_PATH%\bin\colmap" %COMMAND% %ARGUMENTS%
```

Comment: Please read first [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564) It explains in full details how the default shell interpreter `cmd.exe` on Windows searches for the file specified with just the file name like `colmap`. If __system__ or __user__ `PATH` and so finally __local__ `PATH` contains first the directory containing `colmap.bat`, there can be used just `colmap` in Python script file in the arguments of `subprocess.run` with `shell=True`.

Comment: The directory `bin` of `colmap` does not need to be included in `PATH` at all if the batch file `colmap.bat` is improved to work really in any use case. The first command line in the batch file `colmap.bat` should be `@echo off` and the second line `setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion` to define completely the required execution environment. The third line should be the first line posted by you modified to `set "SCRIPT_PATH=%~dp0"` to work even for `colmap` installed into a directory of which path contains by chance the character `&`.

Comment: The next two lines should be `set "PATH=%SCRIPT_PATH%lib;%PATH%"` and `set "QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%SCRIPT_PATH%lib\plugins;%QT_PLUGIN_PATH%"`. Please read my answer on [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) It explains the reason for using `"` on environment variable definition exactly as used here required on `colmap` installed for example into `C:\Temp\Development & Test(!)_100%\Colmap`.

Comment: Please note further that `%~dp0` expands to a directory path __always__ ending with ``\``. Therefore the environment variable `SCRIPT_PATH` is defined with a directory path ending already with a backslash. For that reason the concatenation with a folder name like `lib` must be done without using an additional backslash for a 100% directory path which does not need to be corrected by the Windows file I/O API functions on usage later by `cmd.exe` and `colmap.exe`.

Comment: `set COMMAND=%1` should be modified to `set "COMMAND=%~1"` or the batch file will not work later on running `colmap.bat` is called with first argument enclosed in `"` like `"gui"` because of definition of the environment variable `COMMAND` with the value `"gui"` (yes, with the double quotes) resulting in `if "%COMMAND%"=="" set COMMAND=gui` expanding to `if ""gui""=="" set COMMAND=gui` which is causing a syntax error. `if "%1"=="" goto after_extract_argument_loop` should be modified to `if "%~1" == "" goto after_extract_argument_loop` to work also for arguments enclosed in `"`.

Comment: I suggest to modify `if "%COMMAND%"=="" set COMMAND=gui` to `if "%COMMAND%" == "" set "COMMAND=gui"` which defines `COMMAND` even on running `colmap.bat` with first argument being `""` (empty argument string). I suppose that the other arguments are never empty argument strings as otherwise the condition posted above would need to be extended to support also empty argument strings.

Comment: The last posted line `"%SCRIPT_PATH%\bin\colmap" %COMMAND% %ARGUMENTS%` should be modified to `"%SCRIPT_PATH%bin\colmap.exe" "%COMMAND%" %ARGUMENTS%` whereby the `"` around `%COMMAND%` are perhaps not needed although it is better to have them. The last line of the batch file should be `endlocal` for completeness although `cmd.exe` runs implicit `endlocal` before exiting the processing of the batch file.

Answer (score 1):

```
if "%COMMAND%"=="" set COMMAND=gui

set "colmapexe="
for /f "delims=" %%b in ('where colmap.exe') do if not defined colmapexe set "colmapexe=%%b"

if defined colmapexe ("%colmapexe" %COMMAND% %ARGUMENTS%) else echo Colmap.exe not found&pause
```

should work by locating `colmap.exe` and installing it in the variable `colmapexe`